# Javascript Image Canvas return Data and Output

Tags: javascript, string, image, canvas, alert

so I'm working on a new project and I got a little problem.
So, the following code should alert me the data of an image.

Where's my mistake?

```
function convertData( url ){
var image = new Image();
var canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" ),
canvasContext = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

image.onload = function(){
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
canvasContext.drawImage( image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height );
var data = canvas.toDataURL();
alert( "step 1 - finished!" );
return data;
};
image.src = url;
}

function callData( url ){
    var string = convertData( url );
    for ( var i = 0, limit = string.length; i < limit; i++ ){
    alert( string[i] );
    }
    alert( "step 2 - finished!" )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because images load asynchronously, `return data` wont return until long after `convertData` has exited.

The fix is to put any code that relies on `data` inside the onload function:

*Warning: untested code follows*

```
image.onload = function(){
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    canvasContext.drawImage( image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height );
    var data = canvas.toDataURL();
    alert( "step 1 - finished!" );

    for ( var i = 0, limit = data.length; i < limit; i++ ){
        // don't alert(data[i]) because your alert will 
        // trigger thousands of times!
        //alert( data[i] );
    }

    alert( "step 2 - finished! data.length==" + data.length );

};
```

**[ Addition: load 2 images with an image loader]**

```
var imageURLs=[];  
imageURLs.push("firstImage.png");
imageURLs.push("secondImage.png");

// the loaded images will be placed in imgs[]
var imgs=[];

var imagesOK=0;
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

    var data0=imgs[0].toDataURL();
    var data1=imgs[1].toDataURL();

    // compare each element of data0 & data1 for equality
    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks, the main problem is, that I have to call convertData twice, because I want to check if the data of 2 images are similiar.

Comment: I've added to my answer to show how to preload both images so they are both available during equality testing.

Comment: thanks a lot! You've shown me a good way to solve that problem.